# Can not run End to End Test in Angular Seed

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I am trying to follow the AngularJS Fundementals series on PluralSight. The instructor has downloaded and opened up Angular Seed, and runs the `e2e-test.sh` file with no problems.

I use the regular Windows Command window, and so I attempt to follow his lead but with `e2e-test.bat`.

But it isn't working for me, here is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed Karma? http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/index.html

```
npm install -g karma
```

If this installs ok you should be able to check the version from the command line:

```
karma --version
```

Comment: I get `npm is not recognized as an internal or external command` when I type the above into CMD.

Comment: Thanks @Mattl I just did, but still get the `npm not recognised` error :(

Comment: Try rebooting your machine, this should hopefully solve your npm issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking the same course and I ran into the same issue.

You need to use the **Node.js command prompt** instead of the Windows Command Prompt.

If you have Windows 8, go to the Start page (hit the Windows key), then type "Node".
The Node.js command prompt will be one of the results.

Then from there you can install karma, karma junit reporter, etc. and run the test scripts.